# How I can put @string into setHint

Tags: android, android-activity

How I can use `.setHint()` to put a string resource in an `EditText` throught `Activity` code?

I tried this:

```
myEdit.setHint(@string\text);
```

Comment: have you tried `myEdit.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.text));` ?

Comment: no, i had tried `myEdit.setHint(R.string.text)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this like so:

```
myEdit.setHint(R.string.text);
```

In Java, your resources are available through the `R` class. Strings are available through `R.string.your_string_name`, which returns an integer identifier for that String. Passing that identifier to [`getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29) will load the actual String.

Luckily, EditTexts also contain a [`setHint(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29) that takes an integer reference to a String resource, omitting the need to load the String yourself.

Comment: i figured that, but i forgot this.

Answer (score 1):

Resource in Java should be accessed through the automatically generated class `R`.

The correct way to set a `String` on java using `setHint()` is:

```
myEdit.setHint(context.getString(R.string.text));
```

Note: `context` can usually be your activity, like this:

```
myEdit.setHint(MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.text));
```